# Failing to calculate earth's standard gravitational parameter

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am using this equations from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter):

$$\frac{4\pi^2 a^3}{T^2}=\mu$$

**Where:**

$\mu$ = standard gravitational parameter ($\mbox{km}^3 \mbox{s}^{−2}$)

$a$ = the orbiting body's semimajor axis (AU)

$T$ = the orbital period (s)

**For earth:**

$a = 1$

$T = 31\; 556\; 926$

No matter what I do, I always get $3.964e-14$ as an answer while the answer should be $398600.4418$ according to Wikipedia. That is many decimal points off and not completely accurate.

Now my knwoledge of math is not incredible, but I know how to do simple equations like this. I must have made a mistake, but I cannot find what.

Comment: To get it in $km^3s^{-2}$, you should take $a$ in $km$, not in astronomic units.

Comment: If your question concerns numerical calculations, please show those calculations, even if they're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Earth's orbital parameters, you are calculating the sun's standard gravitational parameter.  You need to use the orbital parameters for a satellite of Earth to get the value for Earth.  You also need to keep the units consistent, so the radius should be in km.  For the sun, [it comes out close](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*pi%5E2*%281.49*10%5E8%29%5E3%2F31556926%5E2) at $1.31E11$  For the Earth, I know GEO is $42164$km and $T=0.997\cdot 86400$ seconds, one sidereal day, giving $3.98811E5$ as it should

Comment: Thank you very much! Wikipedia always provides some strange information regarding equations. In the section for two bodies orbiting each other it states that a needs to be in AU. But I also didn't know that the equation is for orbiting objects instead of the parent. Again, thank you very much!